# Binning by boundaries

Tags: binning

What happens in the situation where you have a value that is equi-distant to the upper and lower boundaries when binning by boundaries?

Take the example {26,28,30,34}

Does 30 get converted to 26 or to 34?

Comment: Could you explain what you are referring to?  "Get converted" according to what algorithm?  What are the "boundaries" in your example?

Comment: Sorry maybe converted is not the right verb, the process of binning is to smooth the data. In the case above if the 3rd value (30) was actually 29 then the bin would contain {26,26,26,34} since 29 is closer to 26 than to 34. The two values at the end are the boundaries, and these a fixed, the values inbetween these are modified to the nearest boundary value.